# Moving specific strings between columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe of properties.

```
**Address**      | **Added on**.       | 
15 Smith Close   |  Added on 17/11/22  |
1 Apple Drive    |  Reduced on 19/11/22|
27 Pride place   |  Added on 18/1//22  |
```

I would like to move all those instances of 'reduced on ...' in the 'Added on' column to another column named 'Reduced on' in the dataframe. How would I do this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`pd.DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
df['Reduced on'] = df['Added on'].where(df['Added on'].str.contains('Reduced on'))
df['Added on'] = df['Added on'].where(~ df['Added on'].str.contains('Reduced on'))

df

          Address           Added on           Reduced on
0  15 Smith Close  Added on 17/11/22                  NaN
1   1 Apple Drive                NaN  Reduced on 19/11/22
2  27 Pride place  Added on 18/1//22                  NaN
```

Or another is to use [`pd.Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) & [`pd.DataFrame.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
pd.concat([df['Address'], df['Added on'].str.extract('(?P<Added_on>Add.*)|(?P<Reduced_on>Reduced.*)')], axis=1)

          Address           Added_on           Reduced_on
0  15 Smith Close  Added on 17/11/22                  NaN
1   1 Apple Drive                NaN  Reduced on 19/11/22
2  27 Pride place  Added on 18/1//22                  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks Anoushiravan. Thats sorted it.

Comment: Lol I have just noticed Anoushiravan coded similarly like I do. I let my code in place even if Anoushiravan was the quickest

Comment: @LaurentB. Yeah just keep it. It happens a lot.

Answer (score 1):

**Proposed code :**

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Build Dataframe to work on
df = pd.DataFrame({"**Address** ": ['15 Smith Close' , '1 Apple Drive', '27 Pride place'], 
                   "**Added on**": ['Added on 17/11/22', 'Reduced on 19/11/22', 'Added on 18/1//22']})

# Define the mask m
m = df['**Added on**'].str.contains('Reduced')               

# 1- Move 'Reduced' rows to **New Col**                       
df['**Reduced on**'] = df['**Added on**'].where(m, np.nan)
# 2- Erase 'Reduced' rows from  **Added on**
df['**Added on**'] = df['**Added on**'].where(~m, np.nan) 

print(df)
```

**Result :**

```
     **Address**        **Added on**          **Reduced on**
0  15 Smith Close  Added on 17/11/22                  NaN
1   1 Apple Drive                NaN  Reduced on 19/11/22
2  27 Pride place  Added on 18/1//22                  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work as well:

```
(df[['Address']].join(df[['Added on']]
.set_index(df['Added on']
.str.rsplit(n=1)
.str[0]
.rename(None),append=True)['Added on']
.unstack()))
```

or

```
df['Added on'].str.rsplit(' ',n=1).str[0].str.get_dummies().mul(df['Added on'],axis=0)
```

Output:

```
          Address           Added on           Reduced on
0  15 Smith Close  Added on 17/11/22                  NaN
1   1 Apple Drive                NaN  Reduced on 19/11/22
2  27 Pride place  Added on 18/1//22                  NaN
```